# Add HTML Image to BuddyPress User Profile Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to customize a BuddyPress site and in the process I need to add some extra HTML images to the user profile pages. I am currently messing around in the following directory:

```
www/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp=templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single
```

I have placed images in this directory but cannot seem to get them to show up, I thought I would simply use:

```
<img src="image.png">
```

However this is not the case. Could someone please help me find out **either what the src directory should be for the image in the current dirrectory OR where I need to move the image to?**

Thank you!

Comment: What is the location of the HTML file you are working on?

Comment: It is in the same directory as the image. www/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp=templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/single/ @LloydBanks

Comment: Can you link to an example where this error is occurring?